# Is essence of the Maybe Monad a Proxy for your function?

Tags: clojure, proxy, monads, option-type

Assumptions:

- by *proxy* I mean in the sense of a wrapper like in Spring
- by *your function* I mean something as simple as `(fn [x] (+ x 1))`

Consider the following [from Konrad Hinsen](http://onclojure.com/2009/03/05/a-monad-tutorial-for-clojure-programmers-part-1/):

```
(defn f [x]
  (let [a  x
        b  (inc a)]
    (* a b)))

(defn f [x]
  (domonad maybe-m
    [a  x
     b  (inc a)]
    (* a b)))

(defn m-bind [value function]
  (if (nil? value)
      nil
      (function value)))
```

Now the benefit is that if the value is `nil`, then `m-bind` returns `nil` and the rest of the computation is never called.

My question is: **Is the essence of the Maybe Monad a Proxy for your function?**

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? What are you asking by "ultimately", "Proxy", and "your function"?

Comment: I still don't know what a proxy is because I don't know Spring. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Clojurians seem to prefer syntactic transformations, such as the `some->` threading macro for short-circuiting on `nil`, over algebraic formalisms like the maybe monad.

In either case, whether by code transformation or by monadic structure, the key is manipulating the continuation so that it is never called after a `nil` or `Nothing` is encountered.

You cannot achieve this short-circuiting behavior with just pure individual function wrappers on each individual function in the chain, precisely because they pure. You need to to control the chain of computation itself, which can be done either with code transformation via macros or installation of a continuation algebra via monads.

Comment: I mean without side effects, you cannot alter non-local program flow outside the individual wrappers. Pure functions can have no affect outside their scope. You can of course do this with pure functions, but they have to wrap the _chain_ of computations, as in a monad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the Spring wrappers work but the point about the maybe monad as described in that article is that you write code like this:

```
(defn f [x]
  (domonad maybe-m
    [a  x
     b  (inc a)]
    (* a b)))
```

And the monad mechanisms adds checks *between* the lines. So after each of these statements it checks if the result is nil and if so just returns nil and quits.

So you don't just get nil if you pass in nil, but it also works if `(inc 8)` suddenly returns nil.